# Hibernate: No discriminator found for [class]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Console output:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No discriminator found for Subclass. Discriminator is needed when 'single-table-per-hierarchy' is used and a class has subclasses
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass.validate(SingleTableSubclass.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

I'm getting this error but I absolutely have a `@DiscriminatorValue` on the class.

Annotations for superclass:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name="entity_type",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
```

Annotations for subclass that is contained in the console error:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="keyword")
```

I'm at a complete loss as to what to do.

Edit:

Here are the complete classes:

Superclass

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name="entity_type",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
public class Superclass implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Long segmentId;
    private String entityType;
    private EntityLists positiveEntityList;
    private EntityLists queryExpansionEntityList;
    private EntityLists negativeEntityList;
    private EntityLists queryRestrictionList;

    public Superclass() {
    }

}
```

Subclass

```
@Entity(name = "Subclass")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "keyword")
public class Subclass extends Superclass implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private Long segmentId;
    private String entityType;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="postive_entity_list_id")
    private KeywordLists positiveEntityList;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "query_expansion_list_id")
    private KeywordLists queryExpansionEntityList;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "negative_entity_list_id")
    private KeywordLists negativeEntityList;
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "query_restriction_list_id")
    private KeywordLists queryRestrictionList;

    public Subclass() {
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

Other potentially relevant information (maybe?)

- My application will build, this error occurs when I try to start it.
- I have a custom renaming startegy (snake_case)

Comment: Can you share more complete code please? you can rename your classes   if you want

Comment: What else do you want/need to see exactly? Do you really want entire classes?

Comment: Yes, I think it might help. I also guess that the stacktrace is not complete. It should display the class name.

Comment: I had redacted the original class name. Full classes are up.

Comment: Try to add @DiscriminatorValue(value = "super") to Superclass and let us see what happens

Comment: Literally the word "super" or the name of the super class?

Comment: Tried it both ways. Nothing different.